# proof of the convergence of confidence intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

The confidence interval can be derived intuitively by replacing the standardized mean with the standard normal and variance with sample variance, but is there a formal limit? I'm trying to prove if the following is correct:

> For $z > 0$, $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, $\mathbf{P} \left( \bar{X} - z \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} < \mu < \bar{X}
> + z \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \rightarrow \mathbf{P} (- z < Z < z)$ as $n
> \rightarrow \infty$ (where $S$, $\bar{X}$ are the sample sd and mean for $n$ observations, $X_i$ are iid and the mean and variances exist so CLT can be applied).

So far, I've done the following:

For some RV $Y$,

$\mathbf{P} \left( Y - z \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} < \mu \leqslant Y + z\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}} \right) =\mathbf{P} \left( - S < \frac{Y - \mu}{z /\sqrt{n}} \leqslant S \right)$. By the strong LLN $S^2 \xrightarrow{p}\sigma^2 \Rightarrow S \xrightarrow{p} \sigma$, hence $S \pm \frac{Y - \mu}{z/ \sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{p} \sigma \pm \frac{Y - \mu}{z / \sqrt{n}}\Rightarrow S \pm \frac{Y - \mu}{z / \sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{d} \sigma \pm\frac{Y - \mu}{z / \sqrt{n}}$, hence $\mathbf{P} \left( - S < \frac{Y - \mu}{z/ \sqrt{n}} \leqslant S \right) \rightarrow \mathbf{P} \left( - \sigma <\frac{Y - \mu}{z / \sqrt{n}} \leqslant \sigma \right)$.

But here's where I get stuck, I can't replace $Y$ with $\bar{X}$ as $\bar{X}$ varies with $n$ so there's two limits going on here. How do I proceed?

Comment: [This](http://www.ncssm.edu/courses/math/Stat_Inst/Stats2007/Stat%20and%20Calc/t%20Converges%20to%20N.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @Clarinetist $X$ might not be normal though.

Comment: However, there must be _some_ unstated conditions on $X_i$. At least IID and that its mean and variance exist. For example, I don't think the theorem is true if $X_i$ are Cauchy--or highly correlated..

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes you're right, I've added those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline:

Inetead of $\mathbf{P} \left( - S < \frac{Y - \mu}{z/ \sqrt{n}} \leqslant S \right),$ use $\mathbf{P} \left( - z < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/ \sqrt{n}} = Y \leqslant z \right).$

Find the limit of $Y$ using Slutsky's Theorem (see Wikipedia, if not in your text). Use the CLT on $\bar X$ and the fact that $S$ tends to constant $\sigma$. For an approx. 95% CI with sufficiently large $n$ use, $z = 1.96$ from standard normal tables.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it is in my book.